# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on English Language & Usage breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 14         48
Users destroyed                                 515          0
Users deleted                                    29          0
Users contacted                                  35          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           134      7,121
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               58      4,420
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         13     15,846
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               21      3,705
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                17     17,119
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              200     23,899
Tags merged                                      24          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            35          2
Tag synonyms created                             38          1
Questions unprotected                             3         13
Questions reopened                              154        154
Questions protected                             911        203
Questions migrated                              469        459
Questions merged                                 20          0
Questions flagged⁴                               69      5,634
Questions closed                              4,343      6,418
Question flags handled⁴                       1,413      4,290
Posts unlocked                                   12        179
Posts undeleted                                  57        423
Posts locked                                     38      1,854
Posts deleted⁵                                2,447     12,477
Posts bumped                                      0      7,274
Escalations to the CM team                        4          0
Comments undeleted                              121          0
Comments flagged                                321      8,651
Comments deleted⁶                            10,775     16,694
Comment flags handled                         3,536      5,436
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                 290      8,970
Answer flags handled                          5,990      3,270
All comments on a post moved to chat            224          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: What's the difference between a *destroyed* user and a *deleted* user? (*Destroyed* sounds somewhat permanent—but apparently not, if they can just recreate themselves.)

Comment: Destroyed means all their posts and comments went with 'em, @Jason. Think spammers and such.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! For future cases, it would be more convenient to break out diamonds, non-diamonds, and user #-1 separately. Mostly so I can focus on what the living, breathing, non-diamond users who hang out here did, and not conflate it with bot actions. Happy new year, Shog!

Comment: Posts _unlocked_ by non-mods? I didn't think there was a mechanism for non-mods  to do that.

Comment: These are instances where the system itself unlocks a post, @mitch - for example, rejected migrations are unlocked on the originating site, and timed locks automatically unlock after the time expires. This is one reason why separating Community actions from community actions is troublesome; the act that triggers such system behavior may be far removed.

Comment: It’s the first time, as far as I can remember, that such year-end statistics are made public for all sites. I wonder what promoted SE managers to publish this data.