# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on English Language & Usage over the past 12 months:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  17         46
Users destroyed³                                 316          0
Users deleted                                     15          0
Users contacted                                   53          0
User suspensions lifted early                      1          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue             68      4,748
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue                10      2,784
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue          19     10,627
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue                 5      2,949
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                  9     13,145
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue               138     14,094
Tags merged                                       34          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             52          1
Tag synonyms created                              52          1
Revisions redacted                                 3          0
Questions unprotected                              1          5
Questions reopened                               115         66
Questions protected                              362        262
Questions migrated                               519        234
Questions merged                                   8          0
Questions flagged⁵                                63      2,772
Questions closed                               3,093      4,970
Question flags handled⁵                          937      1,917
Posts unlocked                                     4        120
Posts undeleted                                   44        311
Posts locked                                      13      1,355
Posts deleted⁶                                 2,261     14,707
Posts bumped                                       0      3,929
Escalations to the Community Manager team         16          0
Comments undeleted                               104          0
Comments flagged                                  67      7,155
Comments deleted⁷                              6,884     14,763
Comment flags handled                          2,110      5,102
Bounties canceled                                  3          0
Answers flagged                                  349      7,376
Answer flags handled                           5,734      1,991
All comments on a post moved to chat             155          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11939/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: When I saw the header for this post, I thought it might be a review of Stack Exchange's behavior this year toward its moderators, which hasn't exactly been a model of temperate and respectful judiciousness. But no—if anything, it's a data-based argument for the primacy of nonmoderators in site maintenance and site policy enforcement. So I want to take this opportunity to thank EL&U's diamond moderators for all the hours they spend overseeing the site, resolving conflicts, de-escalating controversies, and encouraging responsible participant behavior. Thank you for your effective work, mods!

Comment: :))) Is it just me or "User Destroyed" cracks you up, too? XD

Comment: English Language and Usage? I wanna die!

Comment: Users may be consternated to know that Shog9 [seems unlikely to be doing this any more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342031), or at least, not in the same detail.