# Who will take up the mantle?

Tags: discussion, moderation, election, moderators

Happy new year!

**tl;dr:** there will be a moderator election some time in March. Start thinking about if you'd like to be elected.

**UPDATE** The community management team have let me know they are working on scheduling it and will be sharing information regarding the election soon!

**UPDATE UPDATE** Question gathering will start on the 7th of March, with nominations starting on the 14th of March.

You may or may not have noticed, but we have not had a [moderator election](https://english.stackexchange.com/election) for quite some time. It's been [six years](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/4) since our last one. The main reason for this is that the moderators have felt that we can cope with the level of work required without extra help.

Towards the end of last year SE staff approached the moderator team and asked if we wanted extra help or if anyone wanted to step down.

Well, I have been thinking about this for well over a year, and I've decided it's time to end my run.

I've been moderating for eight years, and after a while I stopped enjoying it. I did some introspection and asked myself why I was still doing it and the honest answer was that I liked the extra respect that moderators get and I like being a part of the moderator community.

Essentially I like the power but not the job, which doesn't seem like a healthy place to be. So I told SE that I would like to step down, and the moderators have decided that we should at least replace me, so there has been an election scheduled for some time in March. I've said I'd like to stick around until the newbie is comfortable, but then hand in my diamond.

If you're thinking about running let me give you some insights into what it's like.

Before I ran for moderator, I had high hopes that being a moderator means being able to drastically reshape the site and turn it into exactly what the community wants. This is not true. We mostly try to incrementally improve the quality of content on the site. Deleting, closing, editing. Like not being a mod, but with less oversight. We get access to the flag queue, which is a list of posts and comments that users have flagged for some reason. When I started there were a lot more flags, I could handle 20 per day and there would still be dozens left over. These days there are far fewer, but participation in the site has declined as well (check the difference between [2018: a year in moderation](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11939/2018-a-year-in-moderation) and [2021: a year in moderation](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/2021-a-year-in-moderation)).

Flag handling, of course isn't all moderators are good for. One of the most satisfying parts of the jobs for me is destroying spammers. A few clicks and the account is gone, taking the spam with it. We also have to intervene with users who are not happy for some reason, perhaps they're removing their content, or maybe they're stirring up trouble. Talking people down is a useful skill to acquire. I'm not sure if I've truly got it, but I feel like I've improved.

Another user moderation task is finding sock puppets that are being misused. I am not too good at this, so I let other moderators handle it. Some users are so problematic and widespread that there is a coördinated effort between moderators of multiple sites to find them and stop them.

This, handily, brings me on to my favourite part of being a moderator: the moderator community. I will be very sad to lose this connection (this and unlimited editing time for chat messages). These are knowledgeable and friendly people, this includes the community managers that SE employs.

The mod community is very important as you often find yourself not knowing or forgetting how to do something, and they will know. Also, you'll probably happen upon tools you didn't even know existed, thanks to them.

I can recommend being a moderator, if only for a bit, just to get a good perspective on how SE works behind the scenes. You can always stop when you've had enough.

Thanks for having me as a moderator. It's been a ride!

Comment: Eight years is almost an eternity internet-wise. Enjoy your retirement but don't disappear, we still need you :))

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks! I'll be able to use the site with less of a "what's wrong today " mentallity and more of a "who can I help today " one.

Comment: I think being able to correct typis in my comments is second on the list of things I miss from my mod days, the connection with the greater mod community being first. Maybe SE could set up  a team for mods and former mods. It is really nice not to feel obligated to participate on SE when you're feeling burnt out though. Thanks for helping ELU stay on track for all these years.

Comment: Wait... are you dismantling your fireplace?

Comment: @mitch it's a good mantle, one careful owner. pick up only

Comment: @colleenv Thanks. A chat room for old mods, maybe with some rocking chairs and nice sun lounge, current mods say they'll visit, but you see them maybe twice a year.  but yeah, it would be good

Comment: My, how time flies!  You've been a pillar of this place my entire tenure ... which I just looked up, and is also 8 years! You must've been elected soon before I joined. Also, I was shocked when you noted the most recent election was 6 years ago; if I'm being honest, I still kinda thing of the current mods as the "new" mod team, my brain insists they were elected a couple years ago at most.  And @KitZ.Fox, nice to see you here too!  I've missed your voice.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks! It's a bit strange to think how long it's been since the last election, given how often other sites have them, but since the community haven't been clamouring for new mods, and we mods haven't be in need of extra help, it just hasn't come up.

Comment: Probably the question is: given the substantial decrease in traffic and lower participation in the site, does Matt Ed. really need  to be replaced?

Comment: @user66974 the answer is yes. As I said, the moderators have discussed it and come to the conclussion that when I go there will need to be someone to take my place.

Comment: @user66974 Or do you mean Meta Ed?

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you run I’ll vote for you. I know we don’t see eye-to-eye on every philosophical point, but you’re both a veteran and good-hearted person, and in recent years have even earned substantial rep on the big meta. You know how things are supposed to be done.

Comment: @DanBron I would vote for Mari-LouA too, but if you read her profile, you'll see a mod on Meta has made it difficult for her to run. (We would have to convince SE to make an exception.)

Comment: @ColleenV Well, that’s a shame. :( (I’d also vote for you but given you stepped down on ELL, I just assume you don’t want the diamond hat back.)

Comment: Yes, suspended on MSE for one month in October last year. It breaks my heart not being able to run... cough..cough... Even without the suspension, I wouldn't run but I would have at least spent longer than 30 seconds thinking about it. Lots of better candidates out there but do they want to run, that's the question. We'll see who accepts the mantle.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks :) I do miss it sometimes, but I've found I enjoy SE more when I can step away from it without guilt.

Comment: My impression is that being a good mod takes a rare blend of technical knowledge, sound judgment, and equanimity, along with serious dedication to the site. EL&U has been extremely fortunate in this regard, as every mod here has been consistently strong on all of these counts and has kept the good of the site—rather than momentary passions—foremost in mind. Thanks, Matt E. Эллен, for your many years of exemplary service to English Language & Usage!

Comment: I can think of a couple of good people—Mitch and Don Bron.

Comment: @Xanne - I agree. It appears that rather  than an election, it will be the “nomination” of a new Mod.

Comment: @SvenYargs Thank you for your kind words. I would say, if you're thinking of running, there isn't anything to being a mod that is obligatorily technical. There is certainly scope for that kind of thing, but the day to day tools are no more complicated than the regular site.

Comment: @SvenYargs Any chance I could convince you to run? You’re insanely equinimable; I don’t think I’ve ever seen you post a Meta-answer that didn’t start out by steel-manning the opposing camp’s position before making your own case for change. You have the highest rep in the history of the site, surpassing those who made their hay in the heyday of early and enthusiastic participation, and you’ve done it not by picking the low-hanging fruit, but by the hrs work of identifying questions with promise and then *putting the work in*. You’re exemplary.

Comment: If dangling a carrot would incentivize you, you could be the “golden shield” you’ve longer for. And I’d tolerate it, though being intolerant of diamond mods cultivating their pet interests is a well-known peeve of mine. I promise you I will gladly accept that as a compromise (to be fair, because I also happen to trust your instincts on questions of promise. You have no issue calling junk *junk*.)

Comment: @Xanne Thanks for the endorsement. But I don’t trust myself with power (and I worry such a commitment would be even more of a distraction from the work my employers pay me for than EL&U *already* is for me.)

Comment: @DanBron: I'm sorry to hear that you've taken yourself out of the running. I think you'd be an excellent mod—good judgment, high standards, and a sense of humor. But I understand at least part of your reason for saying no. Like you, I'm too busy with paid work to devote appropriate and consistent time to site moderation. Beyond that, I already have the role at EL&U that I want, which is to ask and answer questions that interest me, on my own schedule, without any time pressure or sense of obligation. EL&U has always had more good candidates than mod openings—and will again this time, I'm sure.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен I remember your supervision of the weekly (?) discussions back in the days when I was a newbie on EL&U. I don't even remember what they were called, but the reminders would pop up regularly. You've always come across as a friendly, even-handed mod who cares about the well-being of this site. We've enjoyed the luxury of having a panel of very good mods here. It's a sad day to see you step down, but I respect the reasons you shared. A mod _emeritus_ badge with associated privileges wouldn't go astray if SE was looking for a way to reward good mods who are retiring.

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence! We do have good mods, and I look forward to seeing who joins them next.

Comment: Oh wow. End of an era! I will be very, very sorry to see you go Matt. You've always been an exemplary mod: calm, patient, rational and objective. You will be sorely missed!

Comment: @SvenYargs for what it's worth, I have been a mod of another SE site for around 8 years, and spent at least one of those years moderating three sites, and the workload is never too much. Or, perhaps more accurately, the work load is what you make of it. These are volunteer positions and real life must always take precedence. Mods are mostly free to do as much or as little as they feel like doing. This isn't a job, after all. Mods who are inactive for a long period will be asked to step down, but it really shouldn't be something that takes up a significant amount of time on a daily basis.

Comment: @Terdon thanks. I hope we'll still catch each other in chat somewhere!

Comment: Thank you for all that you have done for the community, Matt!

Comment: The election is open for 2 positions. Is anybody else leaving ?

Comment: @user66974 I think having only three *active* moderators is risky for such a large site as ours. Kitfox, Yoichi, RegDwight and Nohat are moderators who have taken a backseat in recent years. Although they may be quietly working handling flags; it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @user66974 Why don't you nominate yourself? We've had our differences in the past but you know the ropes, you are sympathetic to newcomers, and non-native speakers. I don't think being a native speaker is an essential requirement to do the job well.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - thanks for your support, but I prefer to give my contribution as a user. ☺️

Comment: While we're at it @Xanne. Join the race? The more candidates we have, the greater the participation and you are probably the one user who is currently the most active and visible on the front lines. You have the rep, the experience of being a user, you have also participated on Meta (for me a deal breaker) and I don't think I've ever seen a tactless comment from you ever! Which is the principal reason  why I would not make a good moderator. Think about it Xanne.

Comment: @Mari-LouA How very nice. Thank you. I am hoping *you* will reconsider running, because site needs your enthusiasm for developing questions from new users, and your creativity in the questions you ask.  I had not realized we have two open slots. Maybe you can get a dispensation from the MSE folks.

Comment: @Xanne ahh, thanks but alas I am not eligible. I have been suspended on Meta more times than I care to mention. One mod on Meta and one CM, who might even have that "power", would have conniptions if I asked. So, best not to. If you look back at previous elections on EL&U we had as many as 11 candidates. Never as few as 3 candidates, it ain't healthy for democracy.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think the fewer candidates for mod _could_ in some way be a result of mod events from the past year throughout SE, in connection with a well known user being un-modded without timely explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but Matt, how much time on average per week did you have to spend moderating ELU? And is there a sort of KPI to monitor mod performance?

Asking for potential mods to take note.

Comment: There's no real KPI. The Community Managers do check in on moderators who aren't active for a while, and if you're inactive for a long time (a year, maybe?) you'll get your moderatorship removed (see MetaEd, for example). I probably spend a hour a day moderating (not continuous), but I don't moderate most weekends.

Comment: Feel free to ask this as a real question. I'm sure other moderators would be happy to relate information.